# Validation error messages remain on page while closing modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using [jQuery Validation Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) to validate my form. On modal box validations are working, but when I close the modal box validation messages are remaining on page as it is.

How can I remove them?

Answer (score 2):

Where are you showing the validation messages? You should show the validation messages on the modal box itself, so that it will go off when the box is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer, without having any code, is to manually remove the validation elements from the form, from within the callback of the modal closing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(".cancel").click(function() {
validator.resetForm();
)};
```

link your modal close to a cancel function.